# Spring crud repository - save() tries to insert new rows for many-to-one relationship in child property

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Spring crud repository save() method performs Insert operation if ID is null, otherwise it performs an Update operation. I have the following Entity beans -

```
Student {
 @Id integer studentId;
 ....
 @OneToMany Set<Project> projects;
 @OneToMany Set<Subject> subjects;
}

Project {
 @Id integer projectId;
 ....
 @ManyToOne Student student;
}

Subject {
 @Id integer subjectId;
 ....
 @ManyToOne Student student;
}
```

If I use spring crud repository to perform save() operation on one instance of Project p, it tries to perform insert on all the Subject that p.student has already been associated. And as a result, I get a primary key constraint violation error.

Spring jpa should only insert the Project and not the entire tree of Student and it's set of subjects.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Could you share code how you are creating  and inserting project ?

Comment: Please also clarify what `integer` is. Is it a custom type? A typo? Or anything but Java?

Comment: It is java.lang.Integer, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem is happen when you don't declare `CasCadeType` for Entity associated, Cascade contain several Type :

1. CascadeType.PERSIST : cascade type presist means that save() or persist() operations cascade to related entities.
2. CascadeType.MERGE : cascade type merge means that related entities are merged when the owning entity is merged.
3. CascadeType.REFRESH : cascade type refresh does the same thing for the refresh() operation.
4. CascadeType.REMOVE : cascade type remove removes all related entities association with this setting when the owning entity is deleted.
5. CascadeType.DETACH : cascade type detach detaches all related entities if a “manual detach” occurs.
6. CascadeType.ALL : cascade type all is shorthand for all of the above cascade operations.

the default value is **`Type.ALL`** for your case you must change `cascadeType` base on requirement.

Comment: But everywhere on the internet, it says it's not going to cascade any of the operations by default